# How to build a multi-file document

Tags: sectioning

This is a very basic question but I cannot understand any guides or questions well enough to help me solve it.

I want to build a multi file document, for example so that in each separate file I make notes in a lecture, and I compose them into one large file.

1) What do I type in my main file in order to load the separate files?

2) Where do I save the smaller files?

3) Can I just type text immediately in the smaller files or do I need to start with a preamble including e.g. begin{document}?

Comment: For your use case I would highly suggest using something like [childdoc](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/childdoc), which will allow you to keep a common preamble in the master file while still allowing you to compile the individual lecture files separately. (Childdoc works slightly differently then usual includes, if you choose to use it, be sure to read the documentation carefully.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At its simplest you just need a file, say `main.tex`, that looks like

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\input{lecture1}

\input{lecture2}

\end{document}
```

Then in the same folder have files `lecture1.tex` and `lecture2.tex`, ....

`lecture1.tex` could just say `hello` (or even be an empty file), but usually you would have at least a section heading so

`lecture1.tex` :

```
\section{Lecture One}
something
```

`lecture2.tex` :

```
\section{Lecture Two}
something else
```

Then to process this run   `pdflatex main.tex`  to make a PDF file including both lectures.